# Problem integrating kafka and spark streaming no messages received in spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

My spark streaming context is successfully subscribed to my kafka topic where my tweets are streamed using my twitter producer.But no messages is being streamed from topic in my spark streaming!
Here is my code

```
def main(args: Array[String]){
    val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "127.0.0.1:9093",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest", //earliest/latest
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StreamTweets").setMaster("local[*]")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

    val topics = List("topic_three")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent,
      ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams))
    stream.map(record => (record.key, record.value))
    stream.print()

    stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.foreach { record =>
        val value = record.value()
        val tweet = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(value)
        val map:Map[String,Any] = tweet.get.asInstanceOf[Map[String, Any]]
        println(map.get("text"))
      }
    }

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Code looks fine. How do we know there's data on the topic?

Comment: I have streamed data and have checked using kafka console consumer

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct port? Kafka defaults to 9092, not 9093 like you have in the code here. Or, if you open the SparkUI webpage, does it show the job starts running? And another thing - Spark Structured Streaming might make more sense for processing JSON rather that using `scala.util` packages directly

Comment: My broker one at port 9092 was not available and was giving error.Thats why i created 2 more brokers 9093 and 9094 as ports so gave 9093 for port number.Yes thanks for the advice

Comment: Multiple brokers on one machine will probably cause more problems. What error were you having?

Comment: "Broker not available".I wasnt able to process messages in my kafka topic because of this.So created 2 more brokers with port 9093 and 9094 and everything started working fine

Comment: If you didn't edit the server.properties file and run `kafka-server-start` and aren't using Docker, for example, and nothing else is running on that port, port 9092 should work fine. In any case, you should try removing the stream.map and stream.print lines if you're only expecting the foreachRDD to run, but like I said, SparkSQL would make more sense here to output data just to the terminal

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes took your advice and I am using Spark structured streaming now.Thankyou